# How to separate a number from 3 digits to 3 digits by comma in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, number-formatting

For example, I want to convert the number.

```
select convert(1354256,money) salMoney
```

result:

```
1354256
```

convert  to

```
1,354,256
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function sql server (MSSQL)

```
select format(1354256,'N0')
```